# How to retrive all the documents of firestore at once using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an Appointment Booking application want to retrieve all my documents from firestore at once on a button click. I used this:

```
Future<void> userAppointmentHistory() async {
    String collectionName =
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.displayName as String;
    String doc_id = "YyWqd9VlB1IdmYoIIFTq";
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(collectionName)
        .doc(doc_id)
        .snapshots()
        .listen(
      (event) {
        print(
          event.get("selectedDate"),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

From the above code, I am getting only the specified document id details. So please help me modify the above code so that I get all the document details as I want to display these details on cards as my booked appointment history.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are passing the doc id `String doc_id = "YyWqd9VlB1IdmYoIIFTq";`
You don't want to pass that if you want the full documents.
just pass the collection reference.

**Follow the below code**

```
 fetchData() {
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName);
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        document = snapshot.docs;
      });
      print(document.toString);
    });
  }
```

Comment: have you tried this?

Comment: Yes , I tried but this is getting printed Closure: () => String from Function 'toString':.
and fix to this issue

Comment: change document.toString and change document.toString()

Comment: done that now I am getting [Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'] as output. Why ??

Comment: bro now you are getting the data. That's why ist's showing [Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot]. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rudransh Singh Mahra,

It's as easy as putting text widget in our application.

**Solution**

You did it in right way but by mistake you have passed a specific id of documents in `doc()` as `doc('YyWqd9VlB1IdmYoIIFTq')`. you just need to remove that id from there and you may get your desired output.

**What actually happens :**

In your query you pass specific docId. So that it will returns that specified id document from your collection. To get all the documents from that collection you just need to do as follows,

```
Future<void> userAppointmentHistory() async {
    String collectionName =
        FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.displayName as String;
    // String doc_id = "YyWqd9VlB1IdmYoIIFTq";
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName).doc().get()
  }
```

And you will get your desired output if `collectionName` is valid and exist in firestorm database.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: tried out the code but getting the error which is [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Comment: did you check your collectionName variable value? Is this same as table created in firestore?

Comment: yes, it's exactly the same, I have double-checked it.

Comment: Please, Use updated code. I tried code in my project & it working fine. Still if you're getting error please provide blogs of error.